# PyTorch dataloading “freezes” when running several jobs on a GCP instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a problem when running several python3.7 jobs on one machine (one job per GPU).
Those are machine-learning jobs involving PyTorch dataloading for a large dataset (>1000GB).

With only one job, the training goes well if I use the `pin_memory=True` option of the Dataloader, the batches are provided on time, the gpu utilisation is high. I use 8 workers.
If `pin_memory=False`, the main process waits a bit for the dataloading on some batches, but it is not too bad.

However, if I start a second job, the dataloading “freezes” for every 8th batch (I have 8 workers) for as long as one minute, slowing down the training dramatically. I timed the `__getitem__` and `collate` functions and timing stays short and constant for those functions. It is therefore not a problem of disk throughput or i/o, nor processing.
I found during the “freezes” that all the dataloading workers processes are dominated by Kernel Threads (all cpus are displayed in red color on htop).
Turning `pin_memory=False` does not solve the issue.

So if it does not come from the `__getitem__` nor `collate` functions, where is all that time spent?
What is going on after one batch has been processed by a worker and before it can be consumed in the main process?
Could you recommend some monitoring tools to find out where the problem comes from?

I am working on a GCP linux virtual machine and my data is stored on a SSD drive.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a handful of threads on pin_memory and num_workers on PyTorch forums you might want to check out. From what I can remember, it doesn't seem like there is a solid answer there, even from the devs, as to what you should use and if I recall, pin_memory isnt always helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked those threads on the PyTorch forum but unfortunately could not find a solution to my issue. It seems like there is an operation performed by the dataloading workers that they cannot all perform in parallel and so they are blocking each other.

Comment: I have met the same problem. I have two two job with 8 workers each. Half of The dataloader process stucks after running for a while and the gpu calculate power usage is extremely low. Please share your findings, thanks!